# Create HTML document the same as the Word document

Tags: html, css, justify

I'm working on an online audio book whose content comes from a WORD file. Of course my content is Unicode (Persian font, similar to arabic). Texts copied from Word document and pasted into my application, show small differences in terms of character/word space and/or justify rules. I'm going make my HTML exactly the same as my WORD file (I've applied correct padding in my HTML in order to simulate WORD margins, also WORD document is in a DIN-A4 paper which its size is emulated in my DIV element). What are the best practices for having the best-achievable similarity between the two?

Comment: This seems like a font question rather then an `html` or `css` question. Really, the best thing to do would be to remake the font so it matches (or better yet, use the same font). You could use CSS to style your web font as well.

Comment: I'm using the same font both in WORD and my HTML document (a TTF font).

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset? This should set all your styles to a default setting which will make sure the font you use will style as it was intended. After that, you can adjust your styles as necessary to correct the letter/word spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than re-inventing the wheel, there are a large number of online Word >> HTML converters available - many of which are free! I would suggest leaning on these to at least get the baseline of your HTML and then make any further enhancements on top of this.

Personally I've used https://cloudconvert.com/doc-to-html before, they have an API also so you could automate the conversion.

Hope this helps!